# Session Variables not expiring with iOS, bootstrap and codeigniter

Tags: php, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, session-timeout

I'm currently using Codeigniter / Bootstrap for framework and formatting.

1. My logins are held by session variables, is there any way I can set these to never expire? Login timeouts are very annoying.

I thought I found an answer for this, so I threw this on my login script (because I only care for login reasons). And It doesn't seem to matter and still expires in 15 minutes.

```
$this->session->sess_expiration = 60*60*24*31; //1 month, could set to longer
$this->session->sess_expire_on_close = FALSE;
```

Any guidance would be very much appreciated

live site: http://collecthw.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently that's already set in the config file in codeigniter

See more here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html